# C# erro no evento dymamico botao click

Tags: c#, metroframework

Ao clicar no botao dynamico do evento click tiles , o mesmo abre varios sites carregados do arquivo settings.ini ... no caso deveria abrir um por um relativo ao nome e link mas abre todos ao mesmo tempo.

Obs: estou usando MetroTiles como botoes (Componentes MetroFramework).

Meu arquivo settings.ini

```
  [bot]
  b00=Debian
  b01=Mineos
  b02=Utorrent
  b03=Debian Apache Web Server 
  b04=Debian Mysql Web Server
  b05=Ez Monitor
  b06=Netdata

  [web]
  h00=https://debian:10100/
  h01=https://debian:8443/
  h02=https://debian:8080/gui/
  h03=http://ccstudio.zapto.org/
  h04=http://debian/phpmyadmin/
  h05=http://debian/app/cc/linux/eZ/
  h06=http://debian:19999
```

Meu código

```
      //TILES ADD 

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            var a = new IniFile("Settings.ini");
            var b = new MetroTile();
            var c = new MetroLabel();

            b.Height = 50;
            b.Width = 100;

            b.Margin = new Padding(5, 5, 5, 5);       
            b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
            b.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(b_Move);
            b.Text = a.Read("b0" + i . ToString(), "bot");
            //c.Text = a.Read("h0" + i . ToString(), "web");
            //c.Hide();
            b.UseCustomBackColor = true;
            b.BackColor = GetRandomColor();
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b);
           /// flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(c);
        }

    }
    private void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var a = new IniFile("Settings.ini");
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {

            Process.Start(a.Read("h0" + i.ToString(), "web"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Que erro que aparece ?

Comment: abre todos links ao clicar no 1º botao  (no caso) , e não um link a cada botão

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código está fazendo exatamente o que deveria, embora não seja o que você **quer**. Perceba que no evento `Click` dos Tiles, você percorre o `IniFile` inteiro e abre cada um dos links.

Pelo que eu entendi, você quer que cada `Tile` abra um link associado à ele. Há várias maneiras de fazer isso, mas o mais simples para o seu caso é o seguinte: ao invés de usar o mesmo evento para todos os Tiles, associe um evento diferente para cada um, já no momento da criação.

Veja o código. Removi as outras partes para que fique mais fácil para você visualizar a alteração.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    var a = new IniFile("Settings.ini");
    var b = new MetroTile();

    // ... //

    var link = a.Read("h0" + i.ToString(), "web");
    b.Click += (obj, args) => Process.Start(link);

    // ... //
}
```

Comment: Vitor agradeço pela resposta ,mas o erro continua ainda pior agor aque fiquei perdido de vez obj,args  no visual C# pediu para criar um private EventHandler obj; foi criado mas diz que o args soh como statments

Comment: Estava faltando os parênteses no código. Já editei a resposta caso queira utilizá-la.

Comment: seu esta correto tambem ! era o que eu precisa Obrigado

Comment: a Proposito como seria for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) para que lesse a quantidade de nomes no aqruivo settings ayutomaticamente no lugar do 15 seria uma leitura automatica do settings ini a quantidade se nomes ja salvos ....

Comment: Não sei qual classe `IniFile` você está usando. Dê uma olhada na documentação dela ou poste outra pergunta.

Comment: meu aqruivo ini usado é desta pagina
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-an-ini-file
The tiny class

Answer (score 0):

Eu atribuiria o link na propriedade `Tag` do Tile  e depois pegaria pelo sender que disparou o evento:

```
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        var a = new IniFile("Settings.ini");
        var b = new MetroTile();
        var c = new MetroLabel();

        b.Height = 50;
        b.Width = 100;

        b.Margin = new Padding(5, 5, 5, 5);       
        b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
        b.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(b_Move);
        b.Text = a.Read("b0" + i . ToString(), "bot");

        b.Tag = a.Read("h0" + i . ToString(), "web"); //atribui o link na tag do tile

        //c.Text = a.Read("h0" + i . ToString(), "web");
        //c.Hide();
        b.UseCustomBackColor = true;
        b.BackColor = GetRandomColor();
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b);
       /// flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(c);
    }

}
private void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       Process.Start( ((MetroTile)sender).Tag.ToString() );
}
```

Comment: Obrigado este Resolveu agora funciona botao por botao !

Comment: @carloscoelho que bom, não esqueça de marcar como resposta! obrigado

Comment: só uma observação, você pode declarar `var a = new IniFile("Settings.ini");` fora do loop, pois será igual em todas as iterações, evita esse "desperdício"  .

Comment: a proposito como faria para ler a quantidade de nomes no aqruivo ini e usa-la aqui for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) ao invez de 15 colocaria  o valor que ele leu dos nomes adicionados automaticamente

Comment: teria que ver sua classe que está lendo o ini, e certamente teria uma Lis<> com cada item do ini, abre uma pergunta com essa situação, para verificarmos melhor